# fail2ban multiple logpath directive

Tags: fail2ban

I've created my own custom filter, action etc for fail2ban.

Just have a question about the logpath.

```
logpath   = /path/to/my/file1.log
            /path/to/my/file2.log
            /path/to/my/file3.log
            /path/to/my/file4.log
maxretry  = 3
```

If my jail is set like the above, would fail2ban look for 3 fails in any of the log files? or 3 fails in any of the files?

I want it to be on a per log basis, but don't want thousands of jails.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up fail2ban to read multi log in a jail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/486301/how-to-set-up-fail2ban-to-read-multi-log-in-a-jail)

Answer (score 2):

So far as I'm aware hits in all of the logs in logpath are aggregated to make a decision. It's as if they were all one log file.

Comment: Hmm, that's what i thought, but not what I want!

Comment: Put each log in it's own jail then

Comment: Will have to - just didn't want to